# Can I have pre-installed files, and downloaded files in the same directory?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm working on an app that will include some pre-installed image files that the user can access, and also other image files that will be available via in-app purchasing.  There will also be a XML files that contain details about the images.

I'd like to be able to put all the files in the same place, regardless of whether they are pre-installed or purchased later, but cannot figure out how to do this.

When they purchase an image the app will access my server, and then download the image (and XML) to a private directory, but I cannot figure out how I would put the pre-installed images in the same place.

Ideally I'd like them all in one place, to keep the code clean and simple without having to do things one way for preinstalled images, and then differently for purchased ones.

Can this be done?  Or is there some other way I should be handling this?

Thanks!

Comment: One way would be to write the `pre-installed` image files to a folder in internal storage on app installation. Then, the image files purchased by the user can also be stored in this folder.

Comment: I'm surprised (and disappointed) that Android doesn't have a way to have files automatically installed to the application's private directory. I don't like the idea of duplicating the file, so instead I'll just have a control file that lets the app know where to get the different files.

Answer (score 0):

**First Method:**

Move pre installed images to your private directory on first run of application, later when user purchase image it will get download to same private directory.

**Second Method:**

Create and maintain a xml it will have path for all images and update it (write new image path) when user purchase a new image. Note that it will be complex as you have to parse xml, but will help in handle path  of images.